# Remove illegal file name characters from pandas dataframe column using python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column called `filenames` which contains the names which will be used to save certain objects into csv files. However, many of them contain illegal characters like “?” Or “/“, is there a quick way to remove all of them ?

I tried `dataframe['filenames'] = dataframe['filenames'].str.strip('?/')`  but nothing happens. The characters are still there, what’s the more efficient and safe way to do this?

Comment: `?` is not technically illegal in file names on Unix. (On Windows I guess it depends on the version of Windows, the phase of the moon, and the trend of the MSFT stock.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will do this. You can add as many characters as you want.

`dataframe['filenames'] = dataframe['filenames'].str.replace('?|/', '', regex=True)`

You need to separate characters you want to remove by '|'.

Comment: To further explain why strip() doesn't work. Strip() only detect the start and end of the string. So, any unwanted characters appeared in the middle of the string would not be removed. However, with replace(), you can replace any character(s) in the string regardless of the location of the character(s).

Comment: .str.replace('<|>|:|"|/|\|||?|*', '', regex=True) like this?

Comment: YES! You are correct.In fact it is a synctax for REGEX. You can try it on https://regex101.com/ to see if you are correct